# Express JS Multiple Route files not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, express-router

I am using AngularJS with NodeJS as backend. I have 2 route files - ***route1.api.js*** and ***route2.api.js***. They are used in ***server.js*** as follows:

```
const route1Api= require("./src/api/route1.api");
const route2Api= require("./src/api/route2.api");

app.use("/api/route1/", route1Api);
app.use("/api/route2/", route2Api);
```

***route1.api.js*** and ***route2.api.js*** have similar code like the following:

```
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/whatever", (req, res) => {
// Code
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am accessing these routes from 2 different Angular data service files:

In ***route1.data.service.js***

```
postRoute1() {
    console.log("Route1");
    return this._http
      .post("/api/route1/whatever", postData)
      .map(result => console.log(result));
}
```

In ***route2.data.service.js***

```
postRoute2() {
    console.log("Route2");
    return this._http
      .post("/api/route2/whatever", postData)
      .map(result => console.log(result));
}
```

Now, the problem is that ***route1*** is working fine, but ***route2*** isn't. The ***postRoute2()*** method works only up to the ***console.log()*** line but not beyond that. What could be the problem?

***route2.api.js*** code:

```
router.post("/whatever", (req, res) => {
  console.log("API hit");
  User.find({}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) res.status(500);
    if (!user) res.status(204);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  });
});
```

Comment: the route is working, are you getting any error?

Comment: @RahulSharma No errors. "Route2" is written to the console. But the API is not getting called.

Comment: try this and check are you getting response or not  `app.use("/api/route2/", route1Api);`

Comment: @RahulSharma No. Still no response. The API is not being hit at all.

Comment: can you upload route2Api code also?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Yes. Even if something is wrong with the returned data, it still should show "API hit" in the console, right?

Comment: you are doing `module.exports = router;` right inside route2.api.js?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes.

Comment: @RahulSharma Any idea?

Comment: The code looks fine to me.

Comment: I moved the API code from route2.api.js to route1.api.js and accessed it from route1.data.service. Still no luck.

Comment: I think problem inside `route2.api.js`

Comment: If it was, then why doesn't it work when I wrote the same API in route1.api.js and called it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening can you remove last / from `app.use("/api/route2", route2Api);` and try

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: @RahulSharma Found the issue. Used .subscribe instead of .map after the query and it works now! But why?

Comment: Because unless n until you subscribe It'll not an API.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the postRoute2() method as:

```
postRoute2() {
    console.log("Route2");
    return this._http
      .post("/api/route2/whatever", postData)
      .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
}
```